SHAP DeepExplainer Error: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'as_list' 'device' (CNN, LSTM model)
I compiled, fit the CNN LSTM model.
normalized_train_data is my whole dataset, which I have split to training and test set.
I want to see features' contribution by running shpaley test.
The code even fails at the first line.
normalized_train_data.shape is (336, 1400, 25)
import shap

explainer = shap.DeepExplainer(model=model, data = normalized_train_data[0:10])
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(normalized_test_data[0:10])


lowering the shap version did not help
